# Objective-C class in Swift treaten as optional

Tags: ios, swift

I have Swift project and Obj-C class declared like:

```
@interface QPOSScannerObjC : NSObject <BluetoothDelegate2Mode>
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<QPOSScannerProtocol> delegate;
```

In my other Swift class when i try to create instance of that class i try this:

```
let scanner: QPOSScannerObjC = {
        let scn = QPOSScannerObjC()
        return scn
    }()
```

However i code compiler error at line `return scn` - `Value of optional type 'QPOSScannerObjC?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Why is it optional? Above code should work and it work with other Obj-C classes well.

Comment: You have to use `_Nonnull`, check [this link](http://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) for more info about how Obj-C handles nullability :)

Comment: @JillevdW ok thanks :)